How can I calculate $\int \frac{1}{y'(x)}dy$?
I am trying to calculate integrals of the form
$$\int \frac{1}{y'(x)}dy$$
Isn't $y'(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}$
such that
$$\int \frac{1}{y'(x)}dy=\int \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}dy= \int dx = x?$$

I think you mean $\int,dx$ which would just be $x+C$. Or is the original integral meant to be $\int\frac{1}{y'(x)},dx$

I corrected the post. So it is $\int dx=x$ but is that correct?

Yes, it is correct. Good job.

It is even faster to directly say $dy = y' (x)dx$ which cancels out the integrand.
